# Debian 10 - Black screen out of nothing/Error logs MCE & firmware

Tags: debian, boot, hardware, firmware

[image][image] [image] I have been working on my debian system and all of a sudden my whole screen went black except for one small white bar at the top left corner.

As this state lasted on for more than one hour, I decided to force a shut down and effect a system restart. Now after the GRUB loader and some messages of system checks which show up usually when booting, it gets stuck in just the same black screen at each boot.

I am at a loss what happened here. If anyone could help me out, I would be very grateful. If I can provide more specific information, please let me know (and possibly how to retrieve that information as I am still new to linux systems).

Thanks a lot in advance

EDIT:
I have booted in the recovery mode and extracted the journal logs. The pictures show an excerpt of the errors it throws at me. It seems that something is wrong with the firmware/cpu/motherboard.

Has anyone experienced this before and can give me a hint as to what exactly is faulty?